# C++ Default Copy Constructor Not Viable

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have 2 classes, `User`, and `BBoard` (Bulletin Board).

I have a member function in `BBoard`, that checks reads data from a file and pushes it back to the vector `userList`. I also have a member function that checks if a `User` exists (if the `User` exists, I want to use the default copy constructor and assign it to `currentUser`)

These are the private variables I have in BBoard:

```
// private:
//   std::string title;
//   std::vector<User> userList;
//   User currentUser;
//   std::vector<Message> messageList;
```

This is the member function in `BBoard` that pushes back `User`s:

```
while (inFS >> dataName && inFS >> dataPass) {
  User x(dataName, dataPass);
  userList.push_back(x);
}
```

This is the member function in `BBoard` that checks if a `User` exists and attempts to use the default copy constructor to assign it to `currentUser`.

```
bool BBoard::userExists(const string& uName, const string& uPass) const {
  for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); ++i) {
    if (userList.at(i).getUsername() == uName) {
      if (userList.at(i).check(uName, uPass)) {
        currentUser = userList.at(i);    //<-- HERE
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
BBoard.cpp:153:21: error: no viable overloaded '='
        currentUser = userList.at(i);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./User.h:8:7: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable:
      'this' argument has type 'const User', but method is not marked const
class User {
```

I did not declare a copy constructor in `User`, so I expected the implicitly created one to work. I did not push back a `const User` either.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor
implicit copy constructors have this form: `T::T(const T&)` so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

I can provide any other portions of the program.

Comment: The `this` in the error message refers to `currentUser`.

Comment: The message says "copy assignment operator", not "copy constructor". Constructors create new objects; assignment modifies existing objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with any copy constructor.

```
bool BBoard::userExists(const string& uName, const string& uPass) const
```

This defines a `const` class method. That's what the trailing `const` keyword, at the end of the declaration, means. A `const` class method cannot modify any member of its class, they're all effectively `const` to the method (unless explicitly declared `mutable`, which is not the case here).

```
currentUser = userList.at(i);
```

This attempts to modify a member of the class. Since it is effectively a `const` class member, it cannot be modified.